# AutoLayout in programmatically created UIControl doesn't appear to work

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

I've created a subclass of UIControl called 'TestButton' with a label and an imageview subview. That object is created with a frame, and as part of the init process I create the subview elements.

These 'TestButtons' are created programmatically, I never use them in the StoryBoard.

Code snippet:

```
class TestButton: UIControl {
    var iconImageView: UIImageView?
    var labelView: UILabel?

    required init(size: CGSize, icon: UIImage? text: String?) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height) )

        if ( (icon != nil) && (text != nil) ) {
            self.iconImageView = UIImageView()              
            self.iconImageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.iconImageView?.contentMode = .center
            self.iconImageView?.image = icon
            self.iconImageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow  // test: show bounds

            self.labelView = UILabel()
            self.labelView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.labelView?.text = "Test"
            self.labelView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

            self.addSubview(self.iconImageView!)
            //self.addSubview(self.labelView!)

            // Setup constraints on created subview(s)
            self.iconImageView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
            self.iconImageView?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            self.iconImageView?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
            self.iconImageView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true           
            }
        }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()    
        print("iconframe: \(self.iconImageView!.frame)")

    }
```

In the sample above, I've removed the label from the mix. I'm only trying to get the imageView constraints to work and effectively size the imageView to the view. This does not work, the image appears full size and the constraints appear to have been ignored. I've tried moving the constraints code into updateConstraints and calling that - all appears to work but again the constraints are not applied.

layoutSubviews does get called when you would expect it to be but the imageView frame is unmodified. There are no messages in the output window, it just silently doesn't work.

My question is; have I somehow disabled autoLayout by specifying the parent's frame? I would have expected autoLayout to still work within the bounds of the parent's frame?

Sorry if this has been answered once or many times before. I'm not actually sure what I'm searching for or the correct question to ask, only posted after a day of trawling SO. Thanks

Comment: So I struggled with this for 2 days, then fixed it within 5 minutes of posting this. Arg. For reference, I has a piece of test code I'd left in there calling translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false on the main view.

Comment: The code looks okay to me. But - you didn't post anything about how the TestButton instance is laid out. It looks like the image *should* be the entire size of the button. One last thought - are you turning the autoresizing mask off for the button? You can add **self..translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false** directly inside the init(coder:).

Comment: @kric Consider posting and accepting your own answer if you found the solution yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of TestButton view will depend on how it is constrained within its superview.

In `NSLayoutConstraint`s both participating attributes (or anchors) are equal "partners": with just those four constraints you have, *imageView will take full frame of it's parent* (TestButton), but at the same time *TestButton will be expanded to be big enough for a full-size image*.
You can apply other constraints to TestButton view to prevent the latter.

To understand why standard views behave like that, look at `intrinsicContentSize` property ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html)). It is implemented by standard controls, and tells the auto layout system how big the view should be, purely based on it's content (UIButton or UISwitch are auto-sized like that, for example). UIImageView's `intrinsicContentSize` is the size of its image, that's why it expands full-size if nothing is preventing it.

Comment: This covers it. Thanks again